# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a form through emailJS package added to my React app.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import{ init } from 'emailjs-com';
init("user_ID");


class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { feedback: '', name: 'Name', email: 'email@gmail.com' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <form className="test-mailing">
        <h1>Let's see if it works</h1>
        <div>
        <textarea
            id="test-mailing"
            name="test-mailing"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Post some lorem ipsum here"
            required
            value={this.state.feedback}
            style={{width: '100%', height: '150px'}}
        />
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" className="btn btn--submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
    </form>
    )
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({feedback: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit (event) {
    const templateId = 'template_nbma07k';
    this.sendFeedback(templateId, {message_html: this.state.feedback, from_name: this.state.name, reply_to: this.state.email})

    }

    sendFeedback (templateId,variables) {
      
    window.emailjs.send(
      'service_ID',templateId,
      variables
      ).then(res => {
        console.log('Email successfully sent!')
      })
      // Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
      .catch(err => console.error('Oh well, you failed. Here some thoughts on the error that occured:', err))
    }
  }
```

Upon clicking submit I get the error described in the subject. It seems to be related to the parameters I am trying to send on window.emailjs.send but I got everything well set up on emailjs end.

Any ideas?

export default Contact;

Comment: reading the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-com) ... in the section *"Angular X / VueJS / ReactJS"* - you should be doing `import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';` and `emailjs.send(....`

Comment: thanks @Bravo better now but since I removed the user_ID from the top, it's now giving me this error in the console:

```index.js:1 Oh well, you failed. Here some thoughts on the error that occured: EmailJSResponseStatus {status: 400, text: "The user ID is required. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration"}```. No idea where I should add the ID in the function?

Comment: so, did you still call init?

Comment: I realised init was what was missing so just for someone that follows this problem:

```import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import{ init } from 'emailjs-com';```

these are the imports

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I after realised that, I think there was an error in the actual problem hence why my confusion. I never thought the problem was wrong. Thanks